# React render gif files from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have data from a local JSON file. Each record has some text (string) and a map saved as `.gif`. The gif files I put in a folder inside `./src`.
I need to reference the right map (gif file) to the right record.

Structure of JSON data file:

```
[
    {
        "id": "someid",
        "text": "some text",
        "map": "map name"
    },
    ...
]
```

I have a component like this:

```
const Story = ({obj}) => (
    <Card className="item" id={obj.id}>
        {
            obj.map
            ? (<div className="card-img-none"></div>)
            : (<div className="card-img"></div>)
        }
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{obj.text}</CardTitle>
                {
                    obj.map
                    ? (<div className={obj.map}></div>)
                    : null
                }
            </CardBody>
    </Card>
)
```

And render the `Story` component:

```
import data from './data.json';
...

<div>
    {
        this.state.data
        ? (
            this.state.data.map((i) => (
                <Story obj={i} key={i.id}/>
            ))
        )
        : ('Data not found')
    }
</div>
```

Since the maps are `gif`, I've tried these:

1. import each `gif` and set `if then` statement to check if `object.map == gif file name` and render the gif file as `<img src={mapName}/>`, set css `img {width: 100%}`. This works only for one record since others have `map` key-value pair.
2. create a class in `index.css` for each map (e.g `.mapName {background: url('./gif-file.gif') center no-repeat; background-size: cover;` Then render the map like the code above. It works for all of them.

However, I run into the issue that I have to set the `width` and `height` of the map div to fixed value, setting `width: 100%` or `height: 100%` doesn't work. The values turn `0`.

It seems like there must be a better solution for this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have the same issue, I've figured out a workaround (it works but I'm not sure it's the best practice):

```
import data from './data.json'; // Import data from json file
import map from '<relative path>/map.gif'; // Import gif file with relative path

// Inside the class
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: []
    };
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    data[3].map = map; // Add value to key 'map' of the target element in data array
    this.setState({data});
}
```

Hope this helps.